# Python sqlite query to file with line breaks

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to write an sqlite query to a text file as a readable report(not a csv) for a regular end user. I'm able to write to the file, but I can't get it to have line breaks within the report.

The text file looks like this:

```
[(6, 'Pass', 'Data', 60), (7, 'name7', 'name7', 75), (8, 'name8', 'name8', 99), (9, 'name9', 'name9', 15)]
```

Here's my function:

```
def reportAll():
cursor = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM STUDENTS") #this line might not be needed
output = cursor.fetchall()
reportFile = open("All Students.txt", "w", newline='\n')
reportFile.write(str(output))
reportFile.close()
print("Report saved into 'All Students.txt'")
print("**********")
```

I'm tried hacking in a "\n" into various places with no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: `for line in output: reportFile.write(str(line))`?!

Comment: Didn't work. That just removed the square brackets.

Comment: Then `str(line) + '\n'`. The point is you need to iterate over the list and write each item separately.

Comment: `for line in output:`
        `reportFile.write(str(line) + "\n")`

gives me the same output without line breaks.

Comment: Works fine for me. Please give a [mcve].

Comment: ok, it works if I remove `newline='\n'` from line 4 of the function

Answer (score 0):

For readable reports for a regular end user, I might use [`prettytable`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PrettyTable), as in the following example:

```
import sqlite3
import prettytable

def reportAll(conn):
    cursor = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM STUDENTS")
    output = prettytable.from_db_cursor(cursor)
    output.set_style(prettytable.PLAIN_COLUMNS)
    output.align = "l"
    with open("All Students.txt", "w") as reportFile:
        reportFile.write(output.get_string())
    print("Report saved into 'All Students.txt'")
    print("**********")

def setup(conn):
    data = [(6, 'Pass', 'Data', 60),
            (7, 'name7', 'name7', 75),
            (8, 'name8', 'name8', 99),
            (9, 'name9', 'name9', 15)]
    conn.execute(
        '''create table STUDENTS (
               ID integer,
               FIRSTNAME text,
               LASTNAME text,
               SCORE integer);''')
    conn.executemany('insert into STUDENTS values (?, ?, ?, ?);', data)
    conn.commit()


def main():
    conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
    setup(conn)
    reportAll(conn)

main()
```

Result:

```
ID        FIRSTNAME        LASTNAME        SCORE
6         Pass             Data            60
7         name7            name7           75
8         name8            name8           99
9         name9            name9           15
```